# How to split a very long string column in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have a (very) long single dataframe column and want to split it into multiple columns to make a regular DataFrame out of it. I've tried

```
.tolist() 
zip()
str.extract()
.str.split() 
expand=True
```

which always results in some errors.

Dataframe infos:

```
df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3150708 entries, 0 to 3150707
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       Dtype 
---  ------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       ----- 
 0   CAL_DT,MODEL_NAME,BRAND_FULL_NAME,BRAND_NAME,VENDOR_NAME,OS_NAME,DEVICE_TYPE,_2G_FLG,_3G_FLG,_4G_FLG,WIFI_FLG,BLUETOOTH_FLG,TOUCH_SCREEN_FLG,DUAL_SIM_FLG,GENDER_TYPE_CD,AGE_B,NATIONALITY_CD,NATIONALITY_NAME,SAUDI_NON_SAUDI,DEVICE_COUNT  object
dtypes: object(1)
memory usage: 24.0+ MB
```

Comment: Can you add some data sample which failed?

Comment: do you try `df1 = df.iloc[:, 0].str.split(',', expand=True)` and `df1.columns = df.columns[0].split(',')` ?

Comment: So it seems some messy data.

Comment: that's mean i have to do some preprocessing, Data cleaning right ?

Comment: seems in data is in some row lost `,` 2 times, so `df1 = df.iloc[:, 0].str.split(',', expand=True)` return `22` columns, but `df.columns[0].split(',')` return only `20` values. So error is raised

Comment: it's working Man Thank you a lot !!!

Answer (score 0):

If only splitting values of first column use:

```
df1 = df.iloc[:, 0].str.split(',', expand=True)
```

If possible assign back splitted first column, here not, because different length of `len(df1.columns)` and `len(df.columns[0].split(','))`:

```
df1.columns = df.columns[0].split(',')
```

Comment: ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 28 elements, new values have 20 elements